# Scala objects masked as methods vs actual method (Stream.cons)

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have been going through the Scala Stream collection API and I have noticed that Stream.cons is implemented as an embedded object. What advantage does this have over implementing it as a function? Under what circumstances should one consider using this technique?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an object, it defines `unapply` in addition to `apply`, which let you pattern match on it.